# CNN Image Regression prediction result

Tags: python, image, conv-neural-network, regression, prediction

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path
import os.path

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

import tensorflow as tf

from sklearn.metrics import r2_score


from keras.applications.efficientnet import EfficientNetB3
import gc
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras import layers, models

from keras import Input
from keras.models import Model
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras import optimizers, initializers, regularizers, metrics
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
import os
from glob import glob
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras import optimizers
from keras.layers import Conv2D,MaxPool2D,GlobalAveragePooling2D,AveragePooling2D
from keras.layers import Dense,Dropout,Activation,Flatten
import sys
# Repository source: https://github.com/qubvel/efficientnet
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath('../input/efficientnet/efficientnet-master/efficientnet-master/'))
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping, ReduceLROnPlateau


image_dir = Path('/content/drive/MyDrive/processed')

filepaths = pd.Series(list(image_dir.glob(r'**/*.jpg')), name='Filepath').astype(str) 

TS = pd.Series(sorted([int(l.split('TS_')[1].split('/pre')[0]) for l in filepaths]),name='TS').astype(np.int)
images = pd.concat([filepaths, TS], axis=1).sample(frac=1.0, 
random_state=1).reset_index(drop=True)


image_df = images.sample(2020, random_state=1).reset_index(drop=True)

train_df, test_df = train_test_split(image_df, train_size=0.7, shuffle=True, random_state=1)

train_generator = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255,
    validation_split=0.2
)

test_generator = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255
)

train_input = train_generator.flow_from_dataframe(
    dataframe=train_df,
    x_col='Filepath',
    y_col='TS',
    target_size=(256, 256),
    color_mode='grayscale',
    class_mode='raw',
    batch_size=1,
    shuffle=True,
    seed=42,
    subset='training'
)

val_input = train_generator.flow_from_dataframe(
    dataframe=train_df,
    x_col='Filepath',
    y_col='TS',
    target_size=(256, 256),
    color_mode='grayscale',
    class_mode='raw',
    batch_size=1,
    shuffle=True,
    seed=42,
    subset='validation'
)

test_input = test_generator.flow_from_dataframe(
    dataframe=test_df,
    x_col='Filepath',
    y_col='TS',
    target_size=(256, 256),
    color_mode='grayscale',
    class_mode='raw',
    batch_size=1,
    shuffle=False
)

inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(256, 256, 1))
x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu')(inputs)
x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu')(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D()(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu')(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu')(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D()(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu')(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu')(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D()(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, kernel_initializer='he_normal')(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, kernel_initializer='he_normal')(x)

outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='linear')(x)

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)

model.compile(
    optimizer='adam',
    loss='mae'
)

history = model.fit(
    train_input,
    validation_data=val_input,
    epochs=10,
    callbacks=[
        tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(
            monitor='val_loss',
            patience=5,
            restore_best_weights=True
        )
    ]
)

#Results
predicted_TS = np.squeeze(model.predict(test_input))
true_TS = test_input.labels

rmse = np.sqrt(model.evaluate(test_input, verbose=0))
print("     Test RMSE: {:.5f}".format(rmse))

r2 = r2_score(true_TS, predicted_TS)
print("Test R^2 Score: {:.5f}".format(r2))

null_rmse = np.sqrt(np.sum((true_TS - np.mean(true_TS))**2) / len(true_TS))
print("Null/Baseline Model Test RMSE: {:.5f}".format(null_rmse))
```

[image]

Image is alloy microstrure and TS is tensile strength of alloy.
I thought if I put images in this model this can predict scattered prediction values.
I can't understand why prediction result have almost same values.
And how can I reduce RMSE?
This results terrible RMSE